# How to implement NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to get my counter to go only eight digits past the decimal. The last digit disappears once it gets to 0. Trying to keep the trailing zero to display itself.

I was told to use `NumberFormatter`. How do I get it so that secondUpdateLabel inherits formatter?

```
var secondTimer = Timer()
var secondCounter: Double = 70.000000
var secondDecreaser: Double = 0.000001


func secondStartCounting(initialNumber x: Double, decreaseBy y: Double) {
    self.secondCounter = x
    self.secondDecreaser = y

    self.secondTimer.invalidate()

    let secondTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.38, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.secondUpdateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    RunLoop.main.add(secondTimer, forMode: .commonModes)
    self.secondTimer = secondTimer


}


@objc func secondUpdateTimer() {
    secondCounter -= secondDecreaser

    let secondUpdateLabel = secondCounter

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 8
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8

    // not proper code next. just want to know how to get secondUpdateLabel to inherit the properties I applied to formatter. not sure what the next steps are 
    secondStat.text = 


}
```

Comment: sorry, secondStat.text = formatter.(from: secondUpdateLabel) is not swift yes. I just want to know how i can get secondUpdateLabel to inherit all the properties I assigned to formatter

Comment: you can use the formatter with double variable using the method `formatter.string(for: secondUpdateLabel)`,  however, I recommend it to convert the variable `secondUpdateLabel` into NSNumber object and use like `formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: secondUpdateLabel))`

Comment: formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: secondUpdateLabel)) made the code run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
var secondTimer = Timer()
var secondCounter: Double = 70.000000
var secondDecreaser: Double = 0.000001


func secondStartCounting(initialNumber x: Double, decreaseBy y: Double) {
    self.secondCounter = x
    self.secondDecreaser = y

    self.secondTimer.invalidate()

    let secondTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.0000001, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.secondUpdateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    RunLoop.main.add(secondTimer, forMode: .commonModes)
    self.secondTimer = secondTimer


}


@objc func secondUpdateTimer() {
    secondCounter -= secondDecreaser

    let secondUpdateLabel = secondCounter

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    formatter.usesSignificantDigits = false
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 8
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8

    secondStat.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: secondUpdateLabel))


}
```

Figured out I had to set usesSignificantDigits to false and the last line of code I implemented fixed my issue.

Comment: What's the point of `secondUpdateLabel`? Just use `secondCounter`. Why is it named with `Label` when it is a number, not a label?

Comment: True, true. I literally started coding 2 days ago. So not very good at this.